# How can I check if I run my component on ReactJS or React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am working on a React component that requires to know if it runs in the ReactJS or a React-Native environment

I wanted to create something like this:

```
/MyComponent
  /index.js // Imports native.js or web.js based on the environment
  /native.js
  /web.js
```

Is there a way to do something like this?